# HTTP Response Header required and curl error 52

Tags: http, curl

I am writing a web service and want to minimize the traffic to only the absolute required response data. I have tried sending no headers and just some text but if it is less than 7 characters curl shows curl: (52) Empty reply from server even though I returned something and if I add another char to my response it returns that.

Comment: If you never respond, your client will timeout.  Is this the behavior that you want?

Comment: No I want to respond, but sending a bunch of headers to effectively send a error code for example is a lot of overhead.